# Build fails when adding in MaterialComponents Library for iOS project

Tags: ios, cocoapods, material-design

My podfile for my iOS project is shown below:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.2'

target 'builditbigger' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!


  target 'builditbiggerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'RxBlocking', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'RxTest',     '~> 4.0'
  end

  target 'builditbiggerUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

pod 'Firebase/Core',:modular_headers => true
pod 'Firebase/Database',:modular_headers => true
pod 'Firebase/Messaging',:modular_headers => true
pod 'Firebase/Auth',:modular_headers => true
pod 'Firebase/Firestore',:modular_headers => true
pod 'Firebase/Storage',:modular_headers => true
pod 'GoogleSignIn',:modular_headers => true
pod 'RxSwift',    '~> 4.0',:modular_headers => true
pod 'RxCocoa',    '~> 4.0',:modular_headers => true
pod 'DatePickerDialog', :modular_headers => true
pod 'MaterialComponents', :modular_headers => true

end
```

When I try to build the project in Xcode, the build fails. There are 4 errors. Each having to do with not finding the `mdf_effectiveUserInterfaceLayoutDirection` property of objects of type `MDCThumbTrack` or `UIView<MDCTextInput>`. How do I rectify this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I just uncommented the `use_frameworks!` line, the build succeed